# Get user screen orientation lock react native

Tags: react-native, expo, screen-orientation

I'm using expo screen orientation package to handle my apps screen orientations but it does not take into consideration if the user have turned auto rotate on/off in the device settings.

I tried the react-native-orientation-locker package as well but I can't get that to work at all on my app for some reason.

Is there any way of telling what the user preference is regarding the auto rotate? I can't find any examples of it anywhere. Surely others needed this info as well.